# Draw spline(smooth path) with SkiaSharp lib on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, 2d, skiasharp

I'm making app with using Xamarin forms.

I want to draw a smooth path (spline) with SKPath, but I am unable to find a simple way to achieve this.

Skiasharp does not support it currently unless I make path smoothly myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SkiaSharp supports cubic Bezier curves. So, what you can do, is divide the spline into segments (points determine segment endpoints), and draw each segment using a cubic Bezier curve. To do this, you need to introduce two control points between each point in your spline curve. These points need to be selected so that the curves in neighboring segments connect smoothly.

I just did an implementation of this. The `public static SKPath CreateSpline(params SKPoint[] Points)` method generates a path that you can use to draw a spline between points. You can view the implementation here:

https://github.com/PeterWaher/IoTGateway/blob/master/Script/Waher.Script.Graphs/Functions/Plots/Plot2DCurve.cs

Example:

[image: Spline example]

Comment: Hey Peter, Awesome job. Thanks for your sharing. I appreciate it.

Comment: According to the license on IoTGateway, the code linked here is not available for commercial use (requires a commercial license), so be careful if copy/pasting it.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. It would be elegant if SkiaSharp developers gave a compact solution.

Comment: @Peter Waher, could you please add a disclaimer that you may not use the code for commercial use without a license?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but there are two areas for smoothing:

Anti-aliasing using `SKPaint.IsAntialias`:

```
var paint = new SKPaint {
    IsAntialias = true
};
canvas.DrawPath (path, paint);
```

Path Curves:

If you need the curves in the path, such as round corners, you will need to use the various curve methods. These include, but are not limited to, `SKPath.ArcTo()` and `'SKPath.CubicTo()`:

```
var path = new SKPath();
path.MoveTo(10, 10);
path.ArcTo(SKRect.Create(10, 10, 30, 30), 0, 45);
```

Path docs: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/SkiaSharp.SKPath/

Comment: Hi, Matthew, thanks for reply. I'm finding a way that actually making my path smooth. I believe you would understand what I ask for. The answer you gave is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: My path has not many point, so it's not smooth line. But I can't use ArcTo or CubicTo to make bezier because the Path is not static.

Comment: I think there are many graphic library that provides those feature on other platforms. and I'm looking for same thing in Skiasharp forms.

Comment: The members are instance methods, so just create an instance. I updated the answer a bit to give an example.

Comment: Here is an example of a more complex path: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/master/samples/SkiaSharpSample.Shared/Samples/XamagonSample.cs

Comment: What I mentioned "I can't use" meant that it is not suitable for my situation. Please imagine pencil drawing, and I want to make that SKPath smoothly like looking better than he drew. In this situation, I can not use CubicTo or something to archive it, can I?

Comment: The solution that I though is making SKPath smooth myself by adding more Point with using my hardcording. The feature I mentioned is not provided, right?

Comment: and plus, SKStrokeJoin.Round is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you are doing freehand drawing, you probably are going to have to just do a large amount of points. There is not that much overhead, so you should be OK. Xamarin's SignaturePad does just that using paths. There is also a `SKPath.Simplify()`: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/SkiaSharp.SKPath.Simplify()/

Comment: Also, you can always simplify the path using one of the many algorithms. What I would try is drawing thousands of points, and then on pen up, simplify and store that. Basically, all the paths will be simplified, except the one currently being drawn.

Comment: Hi Matthew again, the freehand drawing was just example, and it might have been wrong example. Actually what I'm doing is drawing graph, which has a few points. And I want to make it smooth rather than ugly and rough graph because they have a few points. They are many graph library or framework on the other platform which makes shape of graph smooth with using few points on many other platform. That's what I'm trying to do actually.

Comment: I wanted to know if this feature is provided. Answer will be no right?

Comment: This is a perfect example to explain what I'm trying to do. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-inverted

Comment: I'm going to try this solution and will share the result. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31859/Draw-a-Smooth-Curve-through-a-Set-of-D-Points-wit